# ActiveAdmin - failed adding custom page page under a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to add a custom page under one of my resources (ActiveRecord) - on the ActiveAdmin site this was listed under the 'belongs_to' section

Something like this:

```
# the model
ActiveAdmin.register Desk do
...
end

# the custom page
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Chair" do
    belongs_to :desk

content do
    para "Hello World"
 end
end
```

in my rack routes a new route is added:
/activeadmin/desks/:id/chair

but when I try to put the route on the browser or refer to it from the code i get the following:

> undefined method `activeadmin_desks_chair_path' for >ActiveAdmin::Helpers::Routes:Module
>   Did you mean?  activeadmin_desk_chair_path
>                 activeadmin_desks_path
>                 activeadmin_desk_chair_url
>                 activeadmin_desk_path

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add full backtrace?